# Normal SQLi statement to Prepared Statement Troubleshoot

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've been trying (to no end) to convert the following normal SQLi statement & after hours of trying I'm still not able to see where I'm going wrong.  The statement is as follows:

```
$get_comments = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM blog_post_comments WHERE post_id='$post_id' AND removed='no' ORDER BY id ASC");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($get_comments);

if ($count != 0) {

    while($comment = mysqli_fetch_array($get_comments)) {

        $comment_body = $comment['post_body'];
        $posted_to = $comment['posted_to'];
        $posted_by = $comment['posted_by'];
        $date_added = $comment['date_added'];
        $removed = $comment['removed'];
        $blog_comment_id = $comment['id']; 


        etc... }
```

Here is the latest version of what I have for the prepared statement:

```
$no = 'no';  

$get_comments = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM blog_post_comments WHERE post_id=? AND removed=? ORDER BY id ASC");
$get_comments->bind_param('is', $post_id, $no);
$get_comments->execute();

$result = $get_comments->get_result();
$count = $result->num_rows;

$get_comments->free_result();

if ($count != 0) {

    while($comment = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $comment_body = $comment['post_body'];
        $posted_to = $comment['posted_to'];
        $posted_by = $comment['posted_by'];
        $date_added = $comment['date_added'];
        $removed = $comment['removed'];
        $blog_comment_id = $comment['id']; 

        etc... }
```

Can anyone see if I'm missing something here?  In the second statement, I'm not getting an error, but I'm also not loading any posts to display.

Comment: enable error reporting and check for errors on the query. I don't see `mysqli_error($con)` anywhere.

Comment: no error is thrown.  I'm only getting one comment post (for example) with the above code.  I did a var_dump for each of the above and they are all returning as expected.  I checked the dB and this is fine as well.  The `$count` is 3 in the `var_dump`, which is correct, but only returning one instance in the while loop.  Could something be wrong here?   `while($comment = $result->fetch_assoc()) {`